# Как узнать максимальный элемент массива

Tags: c#, list

Есть список

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("10;abc");
list.Add("14;hgg");
list.Add("15;xxc");
```

Как узнать максимальный элемент массива list по значению до ; ?

```
var rez = list.Select(x=>x.Split(';')[0]).Max();
```

Так находит максимальный элемент только без второго элемента.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего воспользоваться пакетом [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/):

```
using MoreLinq;
```

```
list.MaxBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(';')[0]))
```

---

Можно без посторонних пакетов, немного менее эффективно, через сортировку:

```
list.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Split(';')[0])).First();
```

Comment: А без пакетов? .

Comment: @Radzhab: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю как на C#, но если тебе известна длина чисел до ";" , то на java это  так :

```
String a;    
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;    
int number;    
int save;   
for(int i = 0; i < list.getSize(); i++ ){   
   a = list.get(i);    
   number = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(0, кол-во символов до ";"))    
   if(number > max){    
      max = number;    
      save = i;    
   }  
}  
list.get(save);
```

Правда, мне кажется, так довольно долго)